# LLDB debugging freezing in code when declaring variable-size std::vector

Tags: c++, vscode-debugger, lldb

I'm using VSCode on an M2Pro Macbook. When stepping through my code for one a certain method, VSCode's debugger freezes and is unable to load local variables. After a lot of prodding my code I found what directly triggers it, but I do not know how to fixe it, for the code runs perfectly fine when not debugging.

Here is a snippet of the code that freezes the debugger:

```
int max_edges = 0;
for (int i=0; i<N_points; i++) {
    max_edges += point_cache.pairedEdgeLen(points_attatched[i]);
}

std::vector<int> TEST_VECTOR(max_edges);
```

In my original code, `TEST_VECTOR` is replaced with an `IdSet` object which is a custom  hash table set class that utilizes `std::vector`. An `IdSet` must be initialized with an initial size that remains static as elements are added to optimize performance. I use a `std::vector` here because this is what is causing the issue. I found that the `lldb-mi` debugger will freeze as soon as it enters a method in which a `std::vector` is declared with a variable size. Further more, if I were to replace `std::vector<int> TEST_VECTOR(max_edges);` with `std::vector<int> TEST_VECTOR(5);` for instance, I see that the debugger will initialize this vector with a huge `int` size. This image is from VSCode at a breakpoint in the method but before `TEST_VECTOR` is initialized.

[image]

I have a couple questions.

Is it bad form to initialize vectors like this? I'm assuming C++ isn't allocating an absurd amount of space for this vector and then resizing it when it gets to the line. I'm using `clang++` as a compiler. I'm guessing that this is  a result of `lldb`.

How can I fix this problem when debugging? I would very much like to step through this code. Should I initialize the vectors with a constant length at the head of the method and then resize when I get to the line I would have declared it?

EDIT: I found that when declaring the vector at the head of the method, `lldb` initializes the vector with size `0`.

Comment: What you are doing should be fine and is usually preferrable to allocating and then resizing. What seems to be happening is the debugger trying to load all of the data for a variable that's not yet in scope, and that's not good behaviour on the part of the debugger. Crom only knows what garbage it's going to get.

Comment: Command-line lldb truncates the display of containers at some reasonable value (with a note telling you it did that) and it possible (and advisable) for UI's to do that as well.  Laying out a quarter of a million array elements isn't really helpful.

Comment: You might also try lldb-vscode adaptor to lldb, rather than the lldb-mi adaptor.  I don't think anyone has worked on lldb-mi in quite some time now, whereas lldb-vscode is under active development.  They might handle this sort of situation better, and if they don't, you can file a bug with the project (part of the general lldb project).